# AttributeError: module 'concurrent' has no attribute 'futures' when I try parallel processing in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to split a process that takes a long time to multiple processes using concurrent.futures module. Attached is the code below

Main function:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
for idx, score in zip([idx for idx in range(dataframe.shape[0])],executor.map(get_max_fuzzy_score,[dataframe[idx:idx+1] for idx in range(dataframe.shape[0])])):
    print('processing '+str(idx+1)+' of '+str(dataframe.shape[0]+1))
    dataframe['max_row_score'].iloc[idx] = score
```

`get_max_fuzzy_score` function:

```
def get_max_fuzzy_score(picklepath_or_list, df):
import numpy as np
extracted_text_columns = list(df.filter(regex='extracted_text').columns)
data_list = [df[data].iloc[0] for data in extracted_text_columns if not df[data].isnull().values.any()]
try:
    size = len(picklepath_or_list)
    section_snippet_list = picklepath_or_list
except:
    section_snippet_list = pickle.load(open(picklepath_or_list,'rb'))
scores = []
for section_snippet in section_snippet_list:
    for data in data_list:
        scores.append(fuzz.partial_ratio(data,section_snippet))
score = max(scores)

return score
```

The function takes values of a few columns and returns the max fuzzy score from a list that is built previously.

Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing.py", line 8, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "/home/naveen/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/home/naveen/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 53, in <module>
    import multiprocessing
  File "/home/naveen/Documents/pramata-ie/data-science/scripts/multiprocessing.py", line 79, in <module>
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
AttributeError: module 'concurrent' has no attribute 'futures'
```

Answer (score 22):

You can import it this way:

`import concurrent.futures`

and use it this way:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers)
```

---

You can also import `ThreadPoolExecutor` this way:

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
```

and use it this way:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps (upvoted). But I couldn't understand why this is happening? If futures is a sub module then we should be able to access it by . (dot) notation.

Answer (score 3):

Don't name your python file as threading.py or multiprocessing.py

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).